# deleteNode Function Errors

Tags: c

This is my delete node function, can anyone help me in seeing what is wrong with it? I seem to be having a lot of trouble as I do not understand some parts of it.

1. How is the pointer to the head suppose to be used? struct lnode** head, I know this is a pointer to the head pointer. However I am not sure if I am using it correctly.
2. The second part of the code, I am not sure if I am correctly connecting the two nodes after deleting the one that the function calls.

   ```
   void deleteNode (struct lnode** head, struct lnode* node) {
           if((*head) == node){
              struct lnode* temp = (*head) -> next;
              free(node);
              free(node->word);
              *head = temp;
           }
           else{
            struct lnode *nextNode = node->next;
            struct lnode *prevNode;
            while((*head) != NULL){
               if((*head)->next = node){
                   prevNode = *head;
                   break;
               }
               else
                   *head = (*head) ->  next;
           }
           prevNode->next = nextNode;
           free(node);
           free(node->word);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: It is unconditionally incorrect to write `free(node); free(node->word);` because the second call is accessing a now-freed chunk of memory.  You must sequence the calls as `free(node->word); free(node);`.

Answer (score 1):

Please try with this modified program. In the original program, there were the following issues.

If the node to be deleted matched with head, then you were freeing the node twice. This will give an exception as you are trying to free a memory which already has been freed.

The comparison in `if` condition required to be `if((*head)->next == node)` instead of `if((*head)->next = node)`

The order of freeing memory is important. Hence `node->word` should be freed prior to freeing of `node`.

```
void deleteNode (struct lnode** head, struct lnode* node) {
     struct lnode *prevNode = *head;
    if((*head) == node){
       struct lnode* temp = (*head) -> next;
       *head = temp;
    }
    else{
     struct lnode *nextNode = node->next;
     while((*head) != NULL){
        if((*head)->next == node){
            prevNode = *head;
            break;
        }
        else
            *head = (*head) ->  next;
    }
    prevNode->next = nextNode;
    free(node->word);
    free(node);
}
}
```

Comment: This code modifies the incoming head. That should not be modified unless the head is the one getting deleted. Before the loop initialize `struct lnode *prevNode = *head;` and in the loop iterate with `prevNode = prevNode->next;`

Comment: @user1952500 .. Thanks.. I missed this part